# Launch console app from console apps

Tags: c++, createprocess

I am using this piece of code to launch a process from a GUI app. but, according to the notes of this code it is not possible to launch a process from a console app. actually i want to do that, I want a console app to launch another console process, please do you have any idea how to do that?

```
// This technique must be used for "console-less" parents such as GUI
//  applications or detached applications.
// Using the STARTUPINFO STARTF_USESTDHANDLES flag, requires that
//  the CreateProcess fInheritHandles parameter be set TRUE so that
//  the file handles specified in the STARTUPINFO structure will be
//  inherited by the child.

    // setup the child process's handles for stdin, stdout, & stderr.
STARTUPINFO childProcStartupInfo;
memset( &childProcStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(childProcStartupInfo));
childProcStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(childProcStartupInfo);
childProcStartupInfo.hStdInput = hFromParent;   // stdin
childProcStartupInfo.hStdOutput = hToParent;    //  stdout
childProcStartupInfo.hStdError = hToParentDup;  // stderr
childProcStartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
childProcStartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

    // Now create the child process, inheriting handles
PROCESS_INFORMATION childProcInfo;  /* for CreateProcess call */

bOk = CreateProcess(
    NULL,           // filename
    pCmdLine,   // full command line for child
    NULL,           // process security descriptor */
    NULL,           // thread security descriptor */
    TRUE,           // inherit handles? Also use if STARTF_USESTDHANDLES */
    0,              // creation flags */
    NULL,           // inherited environment address */
    NULL,           // startup dir; NULL = start in current */
    &childProcStartupInfo,          // pointer to startup info (input) */
    &childProcInfo);            // pointer to process info (output) */
```

Comment: creating a child process from a console app (or any other app) is trivial. Doing so while inheriting handles for stdout, stdin, and stderr redirection is another issue entirely, and appears to be the point (and error) of this code. You may want to read up on that first.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your reply, but do you have piece of code how to call launch a child process from a console app?. thanks!

Comment: *You* have a piece of code that launches a child process. What you *don't* have is a piece of code that sets up the handle inheritance in the fashion you desire correctly. To that i refer you to my prior comment.

Comment: Hi Graig, I understood, but, can you provide some reference how to setup this code to launch process from console app?

Answer (score 1):

did you try [shellexecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? I think that works..

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
ShellExecute(), ShellExecuteEx(), CreateProcess(), system(), _wsystem().

There are a few more, but one of these got to work for you!

Personally, I would go with CreateProcess and than wait for the process to quit (found on google this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/333559/CreateProcess-and-wait-for-result). Notice that system()/_wsystem() are the easiest to use, but if you're not careful they can be exploited !!!

Hope it helps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char* app_to_launch=new char[80];
    strcpy(app_to_launch,"app.exe");

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );


    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        app_to_launch,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );

    }


    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe free that *app_to_launch* ptr (or just make it automatic).